# impish Release no longer has a Release file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-21.04

I am trying to `$ sudo apt update` but I get this:

```
Reading package lists... Done                                                                                                                        
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-backports Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I haven't touched the `Software & updates - other software` OR the `sources.list` just in case some asks.

Exact Ubuntu version.

`$ lsb_release -a`

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 21.10
Release:    21.10
Codename:   impish
```

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/ may be able to help you quicker.

Comment: this is a very good question, but since SO mods are a bit overzealous these days, you should probably post to superuser.com instead.

Comment: if you change `archive` (or in my case `de.archive`) to `old-release` in `/etc/apt/sources.list` it will work again. For example the first URL looks like this now `deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ impish main restricted`

Comment: @user1167662, this isn't about "overzealous mods", but about this question having nothing to do with programming. It's off topic. Please review what is on topic in the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 9):

For those who will find this post later on a more detailed answer is here [21.10 Removed Repositories](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1420077/21-10-removed-repositories)

Support for Ubuntu 21.10 ended the 14th of July 2022 therefore you're going to have to upgrade.

Comment: Use `do-release-upgrade` to upgrade os to the next release

Comment: thanks! The above did get me this far, that bit seems to have been needed (fingers crossed)